# Vagrant Authentication failure after customizing centos 7 .box

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

My goal is to build a customized CentOS 7.9 Vagrant box. For this I provisioned a VM with the [centos/7 box](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7). From there I :

- Create a user
- Add a .ssh folder for this user
- Add a .ssh/authorized_keys with a public key in it
- Add a /etc/sudoers.d/user file to add it as
- Allow password auth in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- Restart the sshd service
- Test the SSH connection with both ssh key and password form my new user

And that is all.

To create a box I turn off the VM and use `vagrant package --base VM_NAME` to generate the package.box file that I then add as a box with `vagrant box add package.box --name vm_modele`

When I try to provision a VM with this new box Vagrant throw an Authentication failure :

```bash
➜  virtualbox git:(DNS) ✗ vagrant up mirror                        
Bringing machine 'mirror' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> mirror: Importing base box 'keos79'...
==> mirror: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> mirror: Setting the name of the VM: virtualbox_mirror_1681293317592_36609
==> mirror: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> mirror: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> mirror: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    mirror: Adapter 1: nat
    mirror: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> mirror: Forwarding ports...
    mirror: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> mirror: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> mirror: Disk cannot be decreased in size. 20480 MB requested but disk is already 40960 MB.
==> mirror: Booting VM...
==> mirror: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    mirror: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    mirror: SSH username: vagrant
    mirror: SSH auth method: private key
    mirror: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    mirror: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    mirror: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

There is a problem with the internal Vagrant SSH key. It seems that it does not bother to inject a new key pair to interact with the machine and just fails.

What am I missing here ?

Here is for record the vagrant file and .yaml file I use :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# # vi: set ft=ruby :

# Specify minimum Vagrant version and Vagrant API version
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

# Require YAML module
require 'yaml'

# Read YAML file with box details
servers = YAML.load_file('../environments/local_minimum.yaml')
servers = servers["servers"]

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "../resources/ssh_keos_key.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/keos.pub"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    cat /home/vagrant/.ssh/keos.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
    sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
    SHELL
        
    servers.each do |vm_config|
        config.vm.define vm_config["name"] do |srv|
            
            srv.vm.box = vm_config["box_name"]
            srv.disksize.size = vm_config["disk_size"]
            srv.vm.host_name = vm_config["hostname"]
            srv.vm.hostname = vm_config["hostname"]
            srv.vm.network :private_network, ip: vm_config["ip_address"]
            srv.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
                vb.memory = vm_config["memory"]
                vb.cpus = vm_config["cpus"]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```yaml
---
servers:
  - name: mirror
    hostname: mirror
    box_name: "vm_modele"
    cpus: 1
    memory: 1024
    disk_size: "20GB"
    ip_address: 192.168.2.70
```